# Root access is required to install to /usr/local/bin while installing ksync

Tags: linux

I am trying to install this library called ksync: https://github.com/ksync/ksync

By doing: curl https://ksync.github.io/gimme-that/gimme.sh | bash

But I always get a "Root access is required to install to /usr/local/bin"

Even if I try to install it with sudo a providing the root password, I get the same message.

No matter if I try on a mac or linux, it's same issue.

Why is that? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run `bash` as root, not `curl`. So it should be:

```
curl https://ksync.github.io/gimme-that/gimme.sh | sudo bash
```

Also, when `sudo` asks for the password, it wants *your* password, not the root password.